# Simplest way to find a non-linear point

Tags: 3d, geometry

I have a line in 3d space: (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2)
I need to find any point in any plane that is guaranteed NOT to be co-linear with this line. 
What would be the easiest and simplest way to find such a point?

Comment: A random point has a very low probability of being colinear with the given line. If the chosen point happens to be colinear (which can be easily checked). You can either pick a new random point or just add a tiny nudge in the tangent direction (if uniformly random is not that important).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neen some non-collinear vector to build needed point.

There is an approach to get perpendicular vector:

```
make vector d = (x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1)
choose component with the largest magnitude (say dy)
and component with the second magnitude (say dx)
make the third (smallest) component zero
exchange two larger components and negate the largest one
p = (-dy, dx, 0)
```

It is perpendicular to source one (note that dot product is zero `p.dot.d==0`)

Add this vector to any endpoint to get non-collinear point.